# when a word in a sentence is input the program identifies all the positions where the word occurs

Tags: python

I need to get my program to identify a word in a string and give it its index e.g. Hello, world, world if i input world would give me "world 1st positions world 2nd position. I have converted string to list and used enumerate, i can index whole string etc its just can't get program to give indexes of same word which is in the same text .

```
def quote():
   quote = " sample quote sample quote sample quote"
   quote1 = quote.split()
   print(str(quote1) + "\n\n");
   word = input("what word would you like to index? ")
   print(quote1.index(word ));
   print("The word you have chosen is placed at index " +
      str(quote1.index(word)))
```

As you can see quite new to all this have been trying all day!!

Comment: Well, `.index()` only returns the first index of the first instance of the searched word.

Comment: If you're using python 2.x, you should also realize that you're using `input()` when you should be using `raw_input()`

Comment: @wilbur The OP's `print` statements looks more like python3

Comment: You right, you right

Comment: You could always go for old-school iteration over the string as an array and detect the words, and their positions, on your own.

Comment: Thanks, but I am stumped if word in array twice, my results only give index position of word once !